# Upgrade Hibernate from 3 to 4 inside Jboss server (WildFly 18.x)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, wildfly

I'm trying to upgrade hibernate from 3 to 4 and running into multiple issues. Here is a configuration we had for v3.

```
  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource datasource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(datasource);
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.company.hs.service");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
  }


  private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "com.company.hs.service.hibernate.MySQL5InnoDBIndexDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
    properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", Boolean.FALSE.toString());

    properties.put("transaction.factory_class", "org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory");
    properties.put("transaction.manager_lookup_class", "org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup");

    properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
    properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", Boolean.TRUE.toString());

    return properties;
   }
```

After upgrading dependency version and class packages itself, I was able to compile and start application.

But then, after trying to execute any write operation against DB I'm getting following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
```

After researching ton of information, there seems to be multiple options to go about it.

**Option 1**:
Override OpenSessionInViewFilter like suggested in [How can I globally set FlushMode for Hibernate 4.3.5.Final with Spring 4.0.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620303/how-can-i-globally-set-flushmode-for-hibernate-4-3-5-final-with-spring-4-0-6)

Though it seems to help, there are multiple edge cases when app behavior changed (i.e. HIbernateTemplate's method `persist` does not update entity id in place while using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`, so instead we have to use `save` method). And in general, concerned about other side effects since it seems that transaction management is not properly engaged here.

**Option 2**:
As it was suggested in https://crunchtech.io/blog/migrating-from-hibernate-3-to-4-with/ instead of using `JTATransactionFactory` we can switch to `CMTTransactionFactory`. Which is seems like something we want to proceed since we want Spring container to manage transactions.
Corresponding spring javadocs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1_to_3.2.0.M2/changes/docdiffs_org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.html

While trying to execute SQL query it fails with
`org.hibernate.TransactionException: Could not register synchronization for container transaction`.

For reference, only this piece changed from original configuration:

```
    properties.put("hibernate.transaction.factory_class", "org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory");
    properties.put("hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class", "org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup");
    properties.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", "org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform");
```

Controversially, Spring's bug tracker suggests completelly opposite approach - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/15230

**Option 3** would be using AOP aspect that will be executed around `@Transactional` for flushing data into DB.

**Option 4** Use JPA

IMHO likellyhood of 3 and 4 is very low.

Multiple examples in internet suggest that migration of Hibernate from 3 -> 4 should work as a charm for Tomcat and most of the issues come when running in Jboss/GlassFish server.
Unfortunately, we run our application inside WildFly.

At this point, I'd appreciate any input on this. Starting with the question what is a general usage paradigm, maybe options mentioned here are completely off and we need to use different mechanism. Or we are missing some crucial piece of configuration.

Corresponding dependency versions

```
Spring - 4.0.5.RELEASE
Hibernate - 4.2.12.Final
WildFly - 18.0.1
```

Comment: Please, can you describe how you are managing transactions?

Comment: @jccampanero as of now (with Spring 3/Hibernate 3) it's managed by application code, meaning all transaction support is done manually using flush(), commit(), rollback() methods. But with upgrade to Hibernate 4 or 5 we are trying to benefit from container-managed transactions and delegate this responsibility to Spring. So, basically replace all custom code with `@Transactional`.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. And, did you try to include the ```org.hibernate.flushMode``` property with a ```COMMIT``` value in the ```hibernateProperties``` method in your original configuration? Didn't it work?

Comment: Please also pay attention in your ```@Transactional``` annotations: make sure you define the correct value for the attribute ```readOnly``` depending on whether or not you need to modify your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to get it working with Spring 4 Hibernate 5 running within WildFly w/o customizing `OpenSessionInViewFilter` or specifying container-specific properies (like  `hibernate.transaction.factory_class` or `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class`).
Key to success was proper usage of `@Transactional` annotation and little bit of tweeking queries itself.

Even more to that, in my test app enabling JTA transactions properties (like prescribed [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/transactions/Transactions.html)) caused side effects like incorrect rollback on runtime exceptions.
These are the properties I was using to enable it:

```
properties.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", "JBossAS");
properties.put("hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class", "jta");
```

Same code w/o these being specified rollbacks all intermediate DB entries as expected. Didn't known why is that yet, but there is no good reason for us to use JTA transactions in the first place.